# Install OS on Galaxy S4 w/ broken screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems, phone, physical-damage

***Note***: This question is about interfacing a Samsung Galaxy S4 with a computer to install a new O/S so that I can use the phone as a server on my personal network.

I have an Samsung Galaxy S4 with a broken screen (no touch input and no visual output); it's been sitting in my closet for months, but it still charges & boots. Now, I want to put it to good use by installing a new OS (e.g. Ubuntu and/or Android) and turning it into a server on my home network (the battery would act as a convenient UPS). However, since the screen is broken I can't access any menus and can't give it any input.

Is there a way to access this phone to perform a fresh OS install (e.g. via USB)?

Comment: If the lack of touch input is your biggest issue: you can [connect peripherals](https://www.howtogeek.com/164783/how-to-connect-mice-keyboards-and-gamepads-to-an-android-phone-or-tablet/) to an Android device using a USB to Micro USB adapter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. To clarify the problem: It's the lack of touch input and visual output--the screen is black.

Comment: I assumed the screen was cracked but the display was still working. My bad!

Comment: I'm voting to close because problem cannot be reproduced as noted by OP in comments

Comment: @Twisty Actually it's quite easy to reproduce: step 1, grab a working phone; step 2,  crush the screen with a harder object. Done!   ... But in all seriousness, why (specifically) do you recommend issue should be closed.

Comment: Actually, I shouldn't have VTC because your question is still answerable even through the answer would not be applicable to you. Close vote retracted.

Comment: Question has been reworded to address off-topic vote

Comment: @AustinD, the goal may be to use the phone in connection with a PC, but the specific problem you're trying to solve in the question is all phone-centered, which makes it off-topic here.  It might be a better fit on the Android site.

Comment: @fixer1234 Got it -- that's the sound bite that I was missing! Thanks for the suggestion to put it on the Android site, I'll repost over there.

Comment: @AustinD could you please share the link where you posted your question (and if it was answered)? I'm also interested and this post shows up in the first page on Qwant.
And Merry Christmas ;)